# How click a div with button role event in the same class multiple elements

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css

So I'm trying to auto-click every button in Instagram's "hide story from" settings by console, and I tried this code :

```js
for (let i = 0; i < 300; i++) {
  document.getElementsByClassName('wbloks_1')[i]
        .addEventListener('click', function (event) {
        });
}
```

unfortunately this doesn't work anyone has a solution?
div element :

```html
<div data-bloks-name="bk.components.Flexbox" class="wbloks_1" style="pointer-events: none; margin-right: 12px; flex-shrink: 0; align-items: center; flex-direction: row; justify-content: flex-end;"><div data-bloks-name="bk.components.Flexbox" class="wbloks_1" style="pointer-events: none;"><div data-bloks-name="bk.components.Flexbox" role="button" aria-label="Toggle checkbox" class="wbloks_1" style="pointer-events: none; display: none;"><div data-bloks-name="ig.components.Icon" class="wbloks_1" style="-webkit-mask-image: url(&quot;https://i.instagram.com/static/images/bloks/icons/generated/circle-check__filled__24-4x.png/219f67ac4c95.png&quot;); -webkit-mask-size: contain; background-color: rgb(0, 149, 246); flex-shrink: 0; width: 24px; height: 24px;"></div></div><div data-bloks-name="bk.components.Flexbox" role="button" aria-label="Toggle checkbox" class="wbloks_1" style="pointer-events: none; display: none;"><div data-bloks-name="ig.components.Icon" class="wbloks_1" style="-webkit-mask-image: url(&quot;https://i.instagram.com/static/images/bloks/icons/generated/circle-check__filled__24-4x.png/219f67ac4c95.png&quot;); -webkit-mask-size: contain; background-color: rgba(0, 149, 246, 0.3); flex-shrink: 0; width: 24px; height: 24px;"></div></div><div data-bloks-name="bk.components.Flexbox" role="button" aria-label="Toggle checkbox" class="wbloks_1" style="pointer-events: none;"><div data-bloks-name="ig.components.Icon" class="wbloks_1" style="-webkit-mask-image: url(&quot;https://i.instagram.com/static/images/bloks/icons/generated/circle__outline__24-4x.png/2f71074dce25.png&quot;); -webkit-mask-size: contain; background-color: rgb(54, 54, 54); flex-shrink: 0; width: 24px; height: 24px;"></div></div></div></div>
```

Comment: `document.querySelectorAll('.wbloks_1').forEach(button => button.click());`, perhaps?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Put all the elements into an array and remove the first element. Click it, call the function again until you have no elements left. Basic queue.

```js
const queueClick = () => {
  // get all of the buttons into an array
  const buttons = Array.from(document.querySelectorAll('.wbloks_1'));

  const next = () => {
    // get the next button from start of the array
    const button = buttons.shift();

    // click it
    button.click()

    // if we have ones remaining, do it again in 6 seconds
    if (buttons.length) window.setTimeout(next, 6000);
  }
  
  // start the first iteration
  next();
}

queueClick();
```

```html
<input type="checkbox" class="wbloks_1">
<input type="checkbox" class="wbloks_1">
<input type="checkbox" class="wbloks_1">
<input type="checkbox" class="wbloks_1">
<input type="checkbox" class="wbloks_1">
```

Answer (score 2):

If you want to add a delay (as per your deleted comment) you could use [`setTimeout`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/setTimeout) to call a function on all of the buttons ([event delegation](https://dmitripavlutin.com/javascript-event-delegation/)) after a certain time (in milliseconds).

To mock this effect here I've added a button container that logs the text content of each button when it's clicked.

The `delayClick` function accepts an array of buttons (from the query selection), grabs the first one, clicks it, and then `setTimeout` is called after a second calling the function again with the rest of the buttons. When there are no buttons left in the array the function returns.

```js
const container = document.querySelector('.container');
const buttons = document.querySelectorAll('.wbloks_1');

container.addEventListener('click', handleClick);

function handleClick(e) {
  if (e.target.matches('button')) {
    console.log(e.target.textContent);
  }
}

function delayClick(buttons) {
  if (!buttons.length) return;
  const [head, ...tail] = buttons;
  head.click();
  setTimeout(delayClick, 1000, tail);
}

delayClick(buttons);
```

```html
<section class="container">
  <button class="wbloks_1">Button 1</button>
  <button class="wbloks_1">Button 2</button>
  <button class="wbloks_1">Button 3</button>
  <button class="wbloks_1">Button 4</button>
  <button class="wbloks_1">Button 5</button>
</section>
```

Additional documentation

- [Destructuring assignment](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment)
- [Rest parameters](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/rest_parameters)

Answer (score 0):

```js
document.querySelectorAll('.wbloks_1').forEach(button => button.click());
```

Thanks @Andy
Delay:

```js
document.querySelectorAll('.wbloks_1').forEach((button, index) => {
  setTimeout(() => {
    button.click();
  }, index * 1000); // Change the delay time (in milliseconds) as needed
});
```

Comment: setTimeout is firing all at 6 seconds.... they are not queued up to be 6 seconds after each....